# Firebase All Users audience not working?

Tags: android, events, firebase, firebase-analytics

We have migrated our app from GCM to FCM, but we got stuck at some points. The Dashboard shows 8 users for the last 30 days:
[image]

But if i set the All Users filter it stops showing the users it previously showed:
[image]

Is this a bug or its something we are not seeing on how this works?
Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a guess: Answers to related questions ([related1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37800052/4815718) and [related2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38221613/4815718)) indicate that some processing for audiences does not occur until the the audience contains at least 10 members.  Maybe you need a few more users to see the audience data.

Comment: Sadly its not that, added new users (currently we have 13 active users in the last month) but filtering by All Users filter still shows 0 activity. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing with 11 users.  I think it's either a bug or the real threshold is not 10 but some larger number.

Comment: @qbix: take a look at this and see if you are having the same issue please: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147957/firebase-dashboard-audiences-probable-bug) I'm going more for the bug version of the problem (or that I don't have enough knowledge about how analytics works)

Comment: Note that on the Audiences tab, the column for Users shows "<10" when you have more than 10.  If you click on the '?' next to Users, the popup explains that audience data is not shown for small numbers of users.  Seems like a good topic for a Bug Report with [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: See my answer below, the threshold is based on Advertising ID, so uninstall/reinstall doesn't count for audience threshold (expect if you reset the advertising id before re-install)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 10 users in an audiences before it shoes any data. Also, if you look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147957/firebase-dashboard-audiences-probable-bug) from the firebase team it says:

> The threshold of 10 is actually based on Advertising Identifiers (and not Analytics "users").

So you need 10 different advertising IDs in your audiences before it shoes any data.